# How do I force a knockout update for a particular HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

The way I understand it, I have an HTML element which is bound to a particular property in a koObservableArray. It's not bound to its own koObservable due to the setup of the structure.

```
<input data-bind="value: A" id="x" />
```

When the form is submitted, a method is called which serializes the knockout view-model to JSON.

This works fine, but now I am adding some input sanitization on the form.

```
function sanitize(){
  //compute sanitized value
  document.getElementById("x").value = sanitized_value;
}
```

Now, obviously this does not update the knockout view-model as well. My question is this: given a particular html element (which is bound to a property in a koObservableArray), how can I force the property in the koObservableArray to update as well?

Ideally, I need to be able to do this without changing any of my knockout code. Really what I want to be able to do is simulate, in javascript, whatever is causing the knockout view-model to update. I had understood that it updates on blur, but calling:

```
document.getElementById("x").blur();
```

Did not cause the view-model to update.

Comment: why not assigning the value to the view model instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be a smartass but you're doing it wrong :)  If you're using knockout, you have to operate on the view model at all times.  Logic, sanitization, etc. should never touch the DOM directly.  Think about the case where you want your view model to be bound to a different template.  Keeping logic separated is the whole point of knockout.

Now, that doesn't solve your problem, but if I convinced you, this will: to do what you're saying, you'd need an observableArray of observables.  So when you make your observable array,  push observables into it and then change them:

```
var viewModel = {
    mainArray: ko.observableArray()
};

// I understand you've got some probably complex mapping logic, let's say you get your array from the server, and then assign it like this:
viewModel.mainArray(arrayFromServer);

// In that case, do this:
ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrayFromServer, function(item) {
    item.A = ko.observable(item.A);
});
viewModel.mainArray(arrayFromServer);

// and now if you're worried about the trip back to the server:
var jsonStringForServer = viewModel.toJSON();
var plainJSObjectForServer = viewModel.toJS();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me convince my boss that we needed to rework the knockout :)

Answer (score 2):

I run into this scenario every now and then, you need the change event!

Here's a demo for it: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/q0yndje2/

Demo code:

```html
<input id="x" data-bind="value: a"/>
```

```js
// Create a view-model
vm = {
    A: ko.observable("a")
}

// Apply bindings; the input should now show 'a'
ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Change the value of the input outside of KO
document.getElementById("x").value = "b";

// Trigger change, to update the VM
var el = document.getElementById("x");
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
el.dispatchEvent(evt);

// Echo the value of the vm.A to the console; it should be 'b'
console.log(vm.A());
```

or if you have jQuery of course you can do the event much more easily, with

```
$("#x").trigger("change")
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the context for the selected element.  From the context, you can access the underlying view model and can therefore change the bound value directly.  Don't mess with the view like that, that's what the view model is there for.

```html
<input id="x" data-bind="value: a"/>
```

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('x');
var context = ko.contextFor(ele);
var vm = context.$root;
vm.a(value);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1q5yxdk/)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not lean on jQuery for something like this any more than you would absolutely have to. The more you steer away from doing it the knockout way, the more you run the risk of tightly coupling your view with your model (thus reducing re-usability). This becomes apparent the more your model knows about the DOM elements inside the view. It creates a tight coupling between what the model expect to be in the view when, in reality, it shouldn't be designed in such a way that it needs to know.

You could just as easily place a submit binding to your form and then sanitize your data right inside of the model and it would be much much cleaner. Here is an example:

```
<form data-bind="submit: ValidateSubmit">
    <input data-bind="value: someField" />
</form>

var myModel = {
   someField: ko.observable(),
   ValidateSubmit: function() {

      //sanitize fields within model here
      //...
      //...
      return true; //ensures submit occurs
   }
};
```